# Workbook.Close is not firing WorkbookBookBeforeClose Event in Excel Addins C#

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-addins

In my ThisAddins.cs am having WorkbookBookBeforeClose Event and am having one button event in Ribbon.cs file in that i written workbook.close (true,workbook.fullname,null) it is not firing the
WorkbookBookBeforeClose Event while working with Multiple file.

Is there anything having to follow for calling workbookBeforeClose Event?

Comment: What code exactly do you have? How and when do you subscribe to the `WorkbookBookBeforeClose` event in the code?

Answer (score 1):

The following code works fine on my side:

```
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Application.WorkbookBeforeClose += ApplicationOnWorkbookBeforeClose;
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        // Catch the before close event
        private void ApplicationOnWorkbookBeforeClose(Excel.Workbook wb, ref bool cancel)
        {          
            MessageBox.Show("ApplicationOnWorkbookBeforeClose");
        }

      

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```